# Error in generating report with java ireport: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error compiling report java source files

Tags: java, jasper-reports

When i press the button designed to create the report, in the PC on which i developed is ok, on another is ok, on another one it gives me the error:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error compiling report java source files : C:.....\file_1188085947562_837366.java

I read, on stackoverflow too, that a fix is to include `Jasper-jdt-compiler.jar`, but in my downloaded zip of `jasperproject` there is no such jar, where can i find it? And why it is not present? Jasper project downloaded is version 6.1.0

Comment: http://community.jaspersoft.com/download it is called jdt-compiler.jar, but try to understand why you have exception, file access, old jasper version not running on java8 ecc.

Comment: @PetterFriberg i already downloaded the library from that link, .zip format, but there is no such jar inside..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done some investigations into this question. The org.eclipse compiler was once called jtd-compiler, but in latest jasper report relase it is called

```
ecj-4.3.1.jar
```

So it is still included in jasper project/lib, but with another name

Have fun

Answer (score 1):

I'm also faced to this error after build .jar file. I fixed this problem by copy jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar file to /dist/bin folder. Try this!

Comment: can you be more specific pls ? you mean put the jar inside the `bin` folder then build the .jar file ?

Comment: Copy 'jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar' file from C:\Program Files (x86)\Jaspersoft\iReport-5.5.0\ireport\modules\ext and add that to your project as dependancy will help you to sort the real error message from the query level. Mostly this will happen due to Database columns mismatch or some other query syntax errors on the report query or sub report queries.