# I am using Netbean for Java, my problem is that I cannot load JRXML report after I export project to run with JAR file

Tags: java, jasper-reports, apache-commons-beanutils

I know that this topic is already existed but, unfortunately, they don't solve my problem.
My code is below

```
try {
            String prID = txt_prno.getText();
            HashMap hash=new HashMap(1);
            hash.put("ProductID",prID);
            InputStream file = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myreports/reportpr1.jrxml");
            System.out.println("path_1:"+file);
            System.out.println("path_2:"+file.toString());
            JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load(file);
            JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
            JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, hash, conn);
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jp,false);// jv = new JasperViewer(jp,false);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
```

Here is my file structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZUNs.png)

This is some error code from CMD. 
It is a very long stack trace

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils
    at org.apache.commons.digester.CallMethodRule.end(CallMethodRule.java:632)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Rule.end(Rule.java:257)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1345)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigester.endElement(JRXmlDigester.java:199)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
```

This is the path of report file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZUNs.png)

Now, their is no more errors after I download and add the following file to my project library `commons-beanutils-1.9.3-bin.tar.gz`.
But, this message appears instead of the error

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error compiling report java source files : C:\Users\IT\report32name_1548766294622_936064.java
```

Comment: and what is the problem you are having? "cannot load jrxml report" .. can't it find the report? can't it work with Jasper?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, refer to the log yes seem like "Unknow source", i do not user the report .jastper but i use the one .jrxml and it works when i running my project in Netbean but, it throw an error when i run .jar file, actually there is error code and i am trying to attached to this 
PS. I am new here

Comment: "JasperDesign", yet you don't use Jasper. Does that reportpr1.jrxml file exist where you claim it to? print the total path of that file, and check if it does

Comment: here is some error
at org.apache.commons.digester.CallMethodRule.end(CallMethodRule.java:632)
        at org.apache.commons.digester.Rule.end(Rule.java:257)
        at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1345)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigester.endElement(JRXmlDigester.java:199)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)

Comment: show the structure of your jar, where the jrxml-file is located

Comment: if you want to provide more information, edit your question and add it there

Comment: the file is exist for sure, how can i print total path of that file ?

Comment: Dont put such information into comments. Always edit your question and provide a [mcve] there. And hint: it doesnt matter at all if you are using netbeans. Your editor used for writing code does not at all matter when asking why some code isnt working.

Comment: I am really appreciated for your suggestion and sorry for inconvenience, i am trying to add more information as much as possible pls

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451052/how-to-include-jars-in-lib-into-project-jar-file-in-netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Your error message indicates you are missing commons-beanutils-x.x.x.jar

if you're using Maven , add a dependency to this jar. Otherwise you can downoad the missing jar, then right-click your Project in Netbeans > Libraries > Add JAR/Folder > select the jar > Open

Comment: Sorry, what is the solution please

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: after i download file commons-beanutils-1.9.3-bin.tar.gz and added to my project library, then no more those error but report still not loaded

Comment: For your new error you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33121822/error-in-generating-report-with-java-ireport-net-sf-jasperreports-engine-jrexce

Comment: Thank you very much funkyjelly, this suggestion lead me to a solution it is working well now after add jasper-compiler-jdt.jar to my project library