# How to fix "JRException: Error compiling report java source files" error?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

After searching I found something to take **XML** as input and make it as **PDF** but i am getting this error.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
@Service
public class PDFGenerationDemo implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String RESOURCES_DIR;
    public static final String OUTPUT_DIR;

    static {
        RESOURCES_DIR = "src//main//resources//";
        OUTPUT_DIR = "src//main//resources//output//";
    }

    public void makeHTML() throws IOException, TemplateException, JRException {
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:jasper.jrxml");
        JasperReport jReport=JasperCompileManager.compileReport(file.getAbsolutePath());
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Document document = 
        JRXmlUtils.parse(JRLoader.getLocationInputStream(RESOURCES_DIR+"sample.xml"));
        params.put(JRXPathQueryExecuterFactory.PARAMETER_XML_DATA_DOCUMENT, document);
        params.put(JRXPathQueryExecuterFactory.XML_DATE_PATTERN, "yyyy-MM-dd");
        params.put(JRXPathQueryExecuterFactory.XML_NUMBER_PATTERN, "#,##0.##");
        params.put(JRXPathQueryExecuterFactory.XML_LOCALE, Locale.ENGLISH);
        params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, Locale.US);
        JasperPrint jPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jReport, params);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jPrint,OUTPUT_DIR+"CustomersReport.pdf");
      }
}
```

**Error**

```
2020-02-28 14:39:44 [http-nio-9005-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public void com.imoveinvest.propertyuploader.controller.SaveOrValidateValuationReport.htmlCall() throws java.io.IOException,freemarker.template.TemplateException,net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException]: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error compiling report java source files: D:\SanjayS\ImoveHome\property-uploade-service\Blank_A4_1582880983002_121813.java .
2020-02-28 14:39:44 [http-nio-9005-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public void com.imoveinvest.propertyuploader.controller.SaveOrValidateValuationReport.htmlCall() throws java.io.IOException,freemarker.template.TemplateException,net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException]: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error compiling report java source files: D:\SanjayS\ImoveHome\property-uploade-service\Blank_A4_1582880983002_121813.java .
2020-02-28 14:39:44 [http-nio-9005-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public void com.imoveinvest.propertyuploader.controller.SaveOrValidateValuationReport.htmlCall() throws java.io.IOException,freemarker.template.TemplateException,net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException]: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error compiling report java source files: D:\SanjayS\ImoveHome\property-uploade-service\Blank_A4_1582880983002_121813.java .
2020-02-28 14:39:44 [http-nio-9005-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error compiling report java source files: D:\SanjayS\ImoveHome\property-uploade-service\Blank_A4_1582880983002_121813.java .
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJavacCompiler.compileClasses(JRJavacCompiler.java:63)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

> I have been struggling a lot with this please help.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you open a command line shell and type "javac"? Does it fail saying the program "javac" isn't found?

It looks like jasper reports is generating Java code and then trying to compile it (javac is the Java compiler), but it can't find the compiler. That may be because it isn't installed, or it may be that it's not on your "path". The details are going to depend on the operating system you're using. But hopefully this provides a clue to what's going wrong and helps you to fix it.

(Actually, a careful look at the diagnostics tells me you're on Windows, which means I'm not going to be able to help with any more detail than this.)

Comment: This thread may also be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33121822/error-in-generating-report-with-java-ireport-net-sf-jasperreports-engine-jrexce?rq=1

Comment: after following whatever u asked like fixing javac in environment and following provided link's solution I'm getting another error which is 
**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler**

And after debugging i've noticed that

**JasperReport jReport=JasperCompileManager.compileReport(file.getAbsolutePath());**
this line is causing the error

Comment: Then you're making progress. Good luck.